# Homotopy vs homeomorphism.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

If we have a topolological space $X$ and 2 auto-homeomorphisms $\phi_1,\phi_2:X\rightarrow X$ then are $\phi_1,\phi_2$ homotopic as well? If so why?

Comment: its clearly not true if your space is not path connected

Comment: Check http://planetmath.org/antipodalmaponsnishomotopictotheidentityifandonlyifnisodd

Answer (score 3):

With $X=S^1$, identity and inversion are not homotopic.

Answer (score 1):

An example to think about is a torus. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_class_group and in particular http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_class_group#Torus